# 1050, "Table 'dolaposcrumy_scrumygoals' already exists"

Tags: django

[Thats my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixQvm.png) When i run migrations i get this error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'dolaposcrumy_scrumygoals' already exists")

Answer (score 0):

Seems your table is already present. If dropping the table is an option, drop dolaposcrumy_scrumygoals and rerun your migration.

If not, checkout the links below or update the question.

https://www.techiediaries.com/resetting-django-migrations/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/

Good luck.